# Finding Groovy on Mac OS after installing it via SDKMAN

Tags: macos, groovy, environment

I am using Mac OS and have installed groovy via SDKMAN. It says that groovy is installed however I do not know where it has been installed or how to open it and if I need to install an environment to open it in. Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

When you install groovy (or other *tool*) via sdkman, it defines an environment variable: `_TOOL_HOME` in this particular case it will be `GROOVY_HOME`.

Run:

```
echo $GROOVY_HOME
```

in terminal and you will know the place where it's installed.

Comment: @RobertJohnston, in the terminal. In the place you used SDKMAN to install groovy.